# Why doesn't my linked list remove multiple duplicates?

Tags: python, class, linked-list, duplicates, nodes

I have the following code:

```
class LinkedList:

  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
```

I added the remove_duplicate() function to this LinkedList class which removes any duplicates except for the first instance in the list.

```
  def remove_duplicate(self, value):
    prev = None
    curr = self.head
    count = 0

    while curr:
        if curr.get_value() == value:
            count += 1
            if count > 1 :
                prev.set_next_node(curr.get_next_node())

        prev = curr
        curr = curr.get_next_node()
```

In my main function, I am doing these series of calls.

```
linked_list = LinkedList()
linked_list.add("john")
linked_list.add("john")
linked_list.add("john")
linked_list.remove_duplicate("john")
print(linked_list)
```

I expected to get

```
['john']
```

But instead I got

```
['john', 'john']
```

Why doesn't my code remove duplicates like it's supposed to?

p.s. there is Node code that i wrote earlier

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, new_value):
        self.value = new_value
        self.next_node = None

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def get_next_node(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_value(self, new_value):
        self.value = new_value

    def set_next_node(self, new_next):
        self.next_node = new_next
```

Comment: can you provide the code to your `set_next_node` function?

Comment: I updated my Node codes

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think the first time your loop runs, you set `curr` to `head`, find a match to `value`, so increase count then move `curr` to `prev` and get the second element as `curr`.

Now, you find a match and drop `curr` from the list. This attaches the next element to `prev.next` (which is `head`). But you haven't changed what `curr` is, so when you leave the `if` , you then replace `prev` with `curr` which you had tried to drop.

So the next element you try to drop after the first, you can't do - i.e. any sequence to two duplicates, the second is ignored before you get back onto the correct chain.

I've found it easier to follow by spelling it out:

```
# self.head
#     |
# [ node1 ].next > [ node2 ].next > [ node3 ].next > None
#     |                |                |
#   val1             val2             val3

prev = None, curr = node1
prev = curr # prev = node1 
curr = curr.next # curr = node2 

prev = node1, curr = node2
# here we change the contents of one of the nodes (node1.next)
prev.next = curr.next # node1.next = node3
# but here we are then placing the `disposed of` node as the previous one
prev = curr # prev = node2
curr = curr.next # curr = curr3

# prev is incorrect here
prev = node2, curr = node3
# here, when theres a match to delete, we then delete the link from the wrong node
prev.next = curr.next # node2.next = None
prev = curr # prev = node 3
curr = curr.next # curr = None
```

As a solution, you need to treat when you find a double and all other times slightly differently, possibly like below:

```
def remove_duplicate(self, value):
    prev = None
    curr = self.head
    count = 0

    while curr:
        # this is just to see which Nodes weren't being removed.
        if curr.value.startswith(value):
            count += 1
            # if this is false, your original update is still used
            if count > 1:
                # here, the first thing to do is get rid of curr,
                curr = curr.get_next_node()
                # and then attach the new curr to the previous Node
                prev.set_next_node(curr)
                # and restart the loop
                continue
        # this is done for any Node which isn't a multiple of value
        prev = curr
        curr = curr.get_next_node()
```

I have made a few guesses at bits of the rest of your code, but if this is run as

```
linked_list = LinkedList()
linked_list.add("john1")
linked_list.add("john2")
linked_list.add("fred")
linked_list.add("john3")
linked_list.add("john4")
linked_list.add("alice")
linked_list.add("john5")
linked_list.remove_duplicate("john")
print(linked_list)
```

you get

```
~$>./linked_list.py 
['john1', 'fred', 'alice']
```

Comment: Then do you think i need to try another method to approach this problem? How can i implement it?

Comment: no, its just slightly rearranging the if statements, and using continue.

Comment: @G.Lee159 Just out of interest, did this solve it for you?

Comment: @G.Lee159 if its solved, you can also mark it as accepted if you want, so the next person along knows that too.